# What do 'L' gear and overdrive do on my Nissan CVT?

Tags: nissan, cvt-transmission

Nissan Sentra, 2015.  I get that the 'L' gear and the overdrive limit the gearing ratio on the CVT, but to what extent for each one?  What if overdrive is off in 'L' gear?  Since there are four options (D+over, D-over, L+over, L-over), is there an analogy here to a geared 4 speed transmission?

Comment: If overdrive is overdrive would L stand for Low? Do you have the handbook? Is it available online?

Comment: I have the owners manual, and it says to use L for engine braking.  It says that turning overdrive off is for engine braking.  While this is true, what's really happening is that these two things put limits on the gearing ratio for the CVT.  However, the owners manual gives no further info...

Comment: @SolarMike, yeah presumably L stands for low.

Comment: The ecu for the engine and the ecu for the ´box are deciding the suitable change points wrt engine load, speed etc... you can select the gear you want and this puts limits that the ecu’s take into account.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Generally (not specific to your vehicle or CVTs) overdrive is a moot point when in **L**. Activating (or deactivating) overdrive only affects the highest gear range, which you will never reach in **L** because the transmission is held (mechanically and/or electronically) to whatever that vehicle's **L** range is.